# Graficar datos de vectores alineados en columnas diferentes en R

Tags: r

Necesito realizar un gráfico en R con este [conjunto de datos](https://www.dropbox.com/s/br5ou2mvoufpw6i/summary.csv?dl=0).

El problema que tengo es que estos datos están ordenados de manera inconveniente.

El gráfico que deseo realizar es un gráfico que represente, para cada combinación de las variables "Value" e "Inst", los valores de cada vector-fila Sn. De tal manera que en el *eje x* tendríamos S1, S2, S3, S4, S5, S6, S7, S8, S9, S1, y en el *eje y* tendríamos el valor. A modo ilustrativo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora bien, como se observa, me gustaría que los valores de **cada** vector-fila de "eses" (S1,..., S10) aparecieran conectados con una línea. Al utilizar `geom_line`, observo que por defecto pinta una sola línea para conectar todos los valores, por lo que no se consigue el efecto deseado.

Por otra parte, me gustaría colorear los datos según la variable "Estatus". Finalmente, como se observa abajo, estoy utilizando `facet_grid` para agrupar los datos en la visualización.

He estado intentando varias cosas. Pero por claridad, pego aquí la idea que he estado intentando en pseudocódigo-R. Obviamente la implementación no es válida en R, pero creo que se entiende la idea que se persigue.

```
library(ggplot2)
p1 <- ggplot(summary, aes(x=[S1,S2,S3,S4,S5,S6,S7,S8,S9,S10]
                         colour=Estatus)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_grid(Inst~Value, scales = "free")+
  theme_classic()
p1
```

Comment: Hola Pyring tengo una duda respecto al problema que tienes veo que tu base de datos contiene mas de una ves la misma combinación de Value e Inst en este caso lo que buscas es que se sumen los valores de la S y después se pinten en la grafica?

Comment: Muchas gracias @RUBEN lopez Me gustaría que se pintara una línea para cada fila de datos. Es decir, en efecto, cada fila de datos contiene un vector independiente de eses. Después me gustaría agrupar por Value e Inst usando un facet grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

con la información que me compartes espero que esta solución sea lo que estas buscando , para que los datos se pueden mostrar por fila es necesario agrupar los valores dentro de la función ggplot, y reacomodar los valores de S para que cada valor de "S" aparezca en una columna y no en filas ya que así es complicado graficarlo la manera en lo que lo logre fue la siguiente:

```
#Leemos los datos 
 datos<-read_csv("C:/Users/rall8/Desktop/Stack/summary.csv")

#Agregamos una columna para agrupar los datos
datos[["Identificador"]]<-c(1:nrow(datos))

#Revismos la nueva columna que agregamos
head(datos)
#Aqui ya se muestra la columna que agregamos como identificador 
# A tibble: 6 x 14
 S1    S2    S3    S4    S5    S6    S7    S8    S9   S10 Value Estatus Inst  Identificador
    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <chr>   <chr>         <int>
1    14    22     8     9     1     7    11    10     8    10 C     D       I0                1
2    15     6    12    16     6     4     4    16    15     6 C     D       I0                2
3    12     8     7    12     4     4    12    13     6    22 C     D       I0                3
4    22     4     5    11    10     6     8     9    13    12 C     D       I0                4
5     5    13    19     9     9     9     3    12    15     6 C     D       I0                5
6     5     6    23     8    11    13    11     6     9     8 C     D       I0                6



#Tranformamos la tabla para poderla usar facilmente con ggplot
datos_ordenados<-datos %>% pivot_longer(cols=starts_with("S"),names_to="Columna_S")

  # A tibble: 6 x 6
 Value Estatus Inst  Identificador Columna_S value
 <chr> <chr>   <chr>         <int> <chr>     <dbl>
 1 C     D       I0                1 S1           14
 2 C     D       I0                1 S2           22
 3 C     D       I0                1 S3            8
 4 C     D       I0                1 S4            9
 5 C     D       I0                1 S5            1
 6 C     D       I0                1 S6            7                      

 #generamos el orden en el que aparecen los datos
 datos_ordenados$Columna_S<- factor(datos_ordenados$Columna_S, levels = 
                 c("S1","S2", "S3","S4","S5","S6","S7","S8","S9","S10"))

 #generamos la grafica
 datos_ordenados %>% 
 ggplot(aes(x=Columna_S,y=value,colour=Estatus,group=Identificador) ) +
                geom_line() +
                facet_grid(Inst~Value, scales = "free")+
                theme_classic()
```

Y la grafica que se obtiene es la siguiente , lo importante es transformar la base para que las columnas queden en una sola columna y  agregar un agrupador

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias @RUBEN lopez , estoy testando este código pero se parece mucho a lo que quiero. Dos preguntas rápidas: 1. ¿por qué aparece S10 en tu eje x en segunda posición? Debería aparecen al final. 2. ¿Se te ocurre alguna manea de mejorar la visibilidad de las líneas? A lo mejor reduciendo la saturación del color?

Comment: Hola @pyring a la primer pregunta lo que sucede es que ggplot2 acomoda los datos no con un orden establecido para eso tiene que  volver la columna a un factor y así indicarle como quieres que lo ordene , ya agregue el código modificado. a tu segunda pregunta , te la contesto con otra pregunta, que es lo que quieres mostrar si es frecuencia de casos me imagino una grafica de boxplot , también me imagino una grafica de puntos  donde el tamaño de los puntos este relacionado a la frecuencia de los datos que aparecen.

Comment: Hola @RUBEN lopez, muchas gracias por la ayuda con esto, me ha sido muy útil. Me sale un último valor en el eje x como NA. ¿Por qué a ti no te sale?

Comment: Bueno, ya está resuelto mediante un na.omit(datos_ordenados)

Comment: Probablemente era por que el set de datos que nos compartiste no venia completo , e incluía algunos con NA pero lo bueno es que se resolvió  na.omit()

Comment: Hola @RUBEN lopez, en el mismo gráfico, ¿se te ocurre algo para que se pinte tan solo una línea para cada Estatus? Es decir, una sola línea que una los valores medios las señales para cada Estatus? Creo que con eso y unos intervalos de confianza podría ayudarme a presentar más claramente esto.

Comment: Me imagino una grafica similar a un boxplot que que marca los rango, valores medios y el 25% y 75% de los datos , pero no se como se vería, tendría que hacer la prueba, aunque podría también ser una grafica  por cada estatus para que se viera menos saturado, por lo que tendrías 5 graficas similares a la de arriba una para cada estatus

Comment: Gracias @RUBEN lopez, para no mezclar he creado una nueva pregunta para este tema: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/425663/graficar-valores-%c3%banicos-puntuados-y-valor-medio-alineado-de-una-variable-agrupad