# Graficar valores únicos puntuados y valor medio alineado de una variable agrupada por niveles en ggplot

Tags: r

Dispongo de un conjunto de datos como [este](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ga42rg8ch3hd9fy/datos.csv?dl=0).

Deseo realizar un gráfico que represente en el eje *y* "value" y en el eje *x* cada uno de los niveles de "Columna_S", que contiene niveles de S1 a S10. Todo ello agrupado por "VS" e "Inst" (con un `facet_grid`) y "Estatus" con `colour`.

La representación gráfica desea realizarse de tal forma que en el gráfico se represente cada valor mediante `geom_point`. Adicionalmente, se desea también dibujar una línea que una los valores medios (e intervalos de confianza) de cada S, por colores.

Estoy intentando varias cosas pero la línea que obtengo es vertical (ver gráfico). Lo que se busca es unir los valores medios de las S de manera horizontal, a lo largo del eje x.

```
ggplot(datos,aes(x=Columna_S,y=value,colour=Estatus, na.rm = TRUE)) +
  geom_point()+
  geom_line()+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,100, by=25), limits=c(0,100))+
  facet_grid(Institution~Value_system, scales = "free")+
  theme_classic()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

También he intentado utilizar `geom_smooth`, que creo podría ser estéticamente interesante y tiene una función para pintar los intervalos de confianza del mismo color.

Adicionalmente también he intentado calcular las medias aparte para pintarlo encima. Pero tampoco he conseguido ensamblar el código correctamente.

```
datos %>%
  group_by(VS,Estatus,Inst, Columna_S) %>%
  summarise(media = mean(value), 
            desvio = sd(value),                             #Estimación de la media
            error_est = desvio / sqrt(n()),             #Error estandar de la estimación de la media. 
            intervalo_sup = media + (2*error_est),      #Techo del intervalo. 
            intervalo_inf = media - (2*error_est)) %>%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aquí hay una forma de hacerlo directamente con `geom_smooth()`

```
ggplot(data = datos_pyring,
       aes(
         x = Columna_S,
         y = value,
         colour = Estatus,  #Para el color de los puntos 
         group = Estatus,   #Para que geom_smooth haga varias líneas
         fill = Estatus)    #Para colorear los intervalos de confianza
       ) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth() +
  #geom_smooth(method = "lm") +  #para ajuste lineal
  facet_grid(Inst ~ VS, scales = "free") +
  theme_classic()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muy simple, lo único un poco extraño es que sin la definición de `group = Estatus` no funciona. No sé por qué, se supone que el `color =`  es suficiente para eso.

## Respuestas anteriores

Si no entendí mal tu descripción del resultado esperado este código debería funcionar:

```
library(tidyverse)
```

### Calculo previamente los estadísticos que voy a graficar

```
datos_pyring %>% 
  group_by(VS,Estatus,Inst, Columna_S) %>% 
  summarise(media = mean(value), 
            desvio = sd(value),                             #Estimación de la media
            error_est = desvio / sqrt(n()),             #Error estandar de la estimación de la media. 
            intervalo_sup = media + (2*error_est),      #Techo del intervalo. 
            intervalo_inf = media - (2*error_est)) -> estadísticos

ggplot() +  #Nada por aquí, defino los datos geom por geom
  geom_point(data = datos_pyring,   #Los datos crudos para los puntos de colores
             aes(
               x = Columna_S,
               y = value,
               color = Estatus,
               na.rm = TRUE    #Este emite un warning (?)
             )) +
  geom_errorbar(
    data = estadísticos,   #Los estadísticos que calculé antes: de acá uso piso y techo para el intervalo de confianza
    aes(x = Columna_S,
        ymin = intervalo_inf,
        ymax = intervalo_sup, 
        #color = algo   #Acá podrías pintar las barras de error 
        ),
    width = 0.4
  ) +
  geom_point(data = estadísticos,   
             aes(x = Columna_S,
                 y = media),
             color = "black") +
  facet_grid(Inst ~ VS, scales = "free") +
  theme_classic()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es un truco bastante común en `ggplot`: tener dos data.frame. Uno con los datos crudos que usas para el `geom_point()` y otro con los estadísticos: la media que usas para `geom_point()` (un valor por cada media de grupo en lugar en uno para cada observación) y el piso y techo de tu intervalo paramétrico que controla la extensión de `geom_errorbar`.

En `ggplot` a cada `geom_*` se le pueden pasar sus datos o dejar que hereden los datos definidos en la primera llamada a la función. En este caso dejo vacía la primera llamada (de lo contrario falla) y defino los datos para cada geom.

## Con líneas en lugar de intervalos

```
ggplot() +
  geom_point(data = datos_pyring,
             aes(
               x = Columna_S,
               y = value,
               colour = Estatus,
               na.rm = TRUE
             )) +
  geom_line(data = estadísticos,
             aes(x = Columna_S,
                 y = media, 
                 group = Estatus, 
                 color = Estatus)) +
  facet_grid(Inst ~ VS, scales = "free") +
  theme_classic()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Las líneas pasan por las medias cada "S" y hay una por Estatus. No indican el error típico, creo que se podría hacer.

Comment: gracias por esta solución. Me gusta la idea, pero creo que el gráfico queda demasiado cargado... Lo que buscaba era una sola línea que uniera los puntos medios de cada S (para cada color = Estatus). ¿Cómo se podría generar dicha línea con geom_smooth y que los intervalos de confianza quedaran sombreados con sus colores? Creo que eso permitiría observar los datos de una manera más límpia...

Comment: Edité la respuesta con una solución que creo que hace lo que buscas: plotea las curvas de ajuste con error con geom_smooth y colorea las curvas y los intervalos. Creo que se parece a lo que mencionas aquí.